# drawable-xdpi folder is a invalid resource directory name

Tags: android

I have a android project which was automatically configured by my Eclipse IDE. Inside the res folder of the project were 3 folders drawable-ldpi,  drawable-mdpi, and  drawable-hdpi. I wish to support xdpi as well so I added the folder in manually and I receive a "invalid resource directory name" problem. I don't know if the following information is relevant but from searching it might be. My minimum supported sdk is 10 and targeted it 15.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a simple spelling mistake. Rename `"xdpi"` to `"xhdpi"`. You're missing the `"h"`

Comment: Fudge ... thanks very much. They should put that in extra big letters in the Android documentation.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :-) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`drawable-xdpi` is invalid, it has to be `drawable-xhdpi`, its `xhdpi` not `xdpi`